# htaccess deny all disables example.com represent as domain.com/index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am working on securing my web server. 
I do not want people to be able to execute files they shouldn't.

I was told that I should deny all and whitelist files that could be executed.
That works. Problem is when i access my domain.com it wont execute example.com/index.php .  if i type example.com/index.php it works.

here is my htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes

Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files /index.php>
Allow from all
</Files>

<Files "index.php">
Allow from all
</Files>
<Files "teacher_login.php">
Allow from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what's a better way to prevent people from executing scripts they shouldn't?

Don't put them on the Web at all.

Put these scripts *outside* of `public_html` on your server, and suddenly nobody can access them! No need for `.htaccess` hacks like what you're trying. And better still, they're still accessible for the server itself - eg.

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../hidden-scripts/something.php");
```

Much better.

Comment: Yes, I understand I m not allowed to touch upload scripts therefore i am forced to do this. Its good answer but IT does not solve my problem

Comment: In that case you should also consider having the scripts themselves first check "am I allowed to be run?" and `die()` if not.